# Can I use Rasp Pi 3 to detect objects from live streaming videos?

Tags: pi-3, performance

I am doing a project on UAV(Unmanned Autonomous Vehicle) for which I need to detect objects from live streaming videos.
Can Raspberry Pi 3 satisfy my needs?
**Also how is Nvidia Jetson compared to Pi 3?**

I have not considered Jetson because it is quite expensive and if Rasp Pi 3 could suffice my needs then I would go for Pi 3.

P.S.:The object Detection will be implemented using Deep Neural Networks so **Will I get fast response on Rasp Pi 3?**

Comment: In low resolution probably yes.